# Get the description of the place from its Name

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am having a small issue here. In my application, the user enters the name of a place, and I should then show him the list of places having the name of the place he entered. so obviously I need to send the entered name to Google Places and I will expect it to return to me a list of descriptions to uniquely identify each place. so is there a way to get this? 
P.S: I searched alot, and I didn't find how to get the description of a place from its name. 
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default API call to search for a list of locations based on a text query:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=PLACE_NAME&sensor=false&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY

This will return a JSON array containing all the locations Google Places found based on what you entered at the PLACE_NAME field each containing some basic information.

If you want a more detailed description you can call:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=REFERENCE_OF_PLACE&sensor=false&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY

Where REFERENCE_OF_PLACE is the reference id (retrieved in the textsearch call) of the place you want to aquire information of.

A google api key can be retrieved by registering at the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

And example how to retrieve and parse JSON can be found [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse).

Answer (score 1):

Android provides Geocoder class through which you can get the details of Locations.

[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)